# ODBC while and foreach loop outputs 2 results in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop, odbc

I have selected Top 5 rows in my database and used ODBC as a connection instead of the natural way of MSSQL connecting. Every time I refresh my page where the while and foreach loop contain, it gives 2 outputs instead of one. Can you help me guys with with

Here's my entire code

```
<?php
            $que = "SELECT top 5 notification FROM notification order by datetime desc";
            $queresa = odbc_exec($conn,$que);
            $rows = array();

            while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $queresa )){ 
                 $rows[] = $myRow;
                   foreach($rows as $row) {
                      foreach($row as $key => $value) {
                           $result = $value;
                           echo "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>
                                   <i class='fa fa-envelope fa-fw'></i><font color='green'>$result</font>
                                </a>";
                      }
                   }
            }
?>
```

Comment: You should do this foreach after while loop.

Comment: You are adding to `$rows` -> `$rows[] = $myRow;` and then looping over the entire `$rows` -> `foreach($rows as $row)`. So on each loop you add 1 more value, and then loop over every value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are iterating array as many time while is iterating, so its
>   happening twice for you. Iterate complete array after `while loop`
>   (fetching data completely).

Consider following snippet:

```
<?php
$que = "SELECT top 5 notification FROM notification order by datetime desc";
$queresa = odbc_exec($conn,$que);
$rows = array();

while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $queresa )){ 
    $rows[] = $myRow;//pushing into $rows array
}

//Now iterating complete array
foreach($rows as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            $result = $value;
            echo "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>
                                   <i class='fa fa-envelope fa-fw'></i><font color='green'>$result</font>
                                </a>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply. Now I understand the error a lot clearer than before and have learned deeper on how to use while and foreach. Thanks a lot.